# ID as an event-parameter for <div> in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery

How can I pass an argument in a function to create  ID? For example in following I want ID_Name as to be taken as `<div>` ID. The following doesn't work. Just to show my intention.

```
function create_drags(ID_Name) {
    $("BODY").append($('<div ID="ID_Name" class="ui-widget-content"><p>Draggable </p></div>'));
    $(ID_Name).draggable();
}
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**
Here is a working fiddle for you to try. http://jsfiddle.net/etdKL/

String concatenation. 
There are two problems 
The first when assigning the Id.
Instead of `ID="ID_Name"` you type `ID="'+ID_Name+'"` Then JavaScript will evaluate ID_Name as a variable instead of a String literal.

```
$("BODY").append($('<div ID="'+ID_Name+'" ...'
```

The second is that you need to use a # in the selector to tell JQuery to use the ID selector resulting in.

```
$(ID_Name) --> $('#' +ID_Name)
```

Comment: I think you mean ID="'+ID_Name+'"

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `$(ID_Name).draggable();` should be changed to `$('#' + ID_Name).draggable();`

Comment: I guess this worked for creating the content but I still cannot call draggable if I use something like $("# +ID_Name+ ").draggable or $("#ID_Name").draggable. Is there something wrong I am doing?

Comment: I guess this worked for creating the content but I still cannot call draggable as $('#' + ID_Name).draggable(); I tried double-quotes and everything but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake that I was passing invalid string content to the create_drag function. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
function create_drags(ID_Name){
    $("BODY").append($('<div ID="' + ID_Name  + '" class="ui-widget-content"><p>Draggable</p></div>'));
    $('#' + ID_Name).draggable();
}
```

There was also a missing '#' when selecting the newly added div.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use String concatenation to include the value of the `ID_Name` or you can create individual DOM elements using jQuery and set the attributes/properties you want to on them, as well as call any other jQuery functions. Code would look something like this:

```
function create_drags(ID_Name) {
    var $div = $('<div/>').attr('id', ID_Name).addClass('ui-widget-content').draggable();
    $div.append('<p>Draggable </p>');
    $("BODY").append($div);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom attributes to pass variables

```
<div id="div_id" custom-attr="other_id"></div>
```

And after that get with jQuery

```
$("#div_id").attr("custom-attr");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function create_drags(ID_Name) {
$("BODY").append(
    $('<div ID="'+ID_Name+'" class= "ui-widget-content"><p>Draggable </p></div>')
);
$(ID_Name).draggable();
}
```

or a jQuery-like way:

```
function create_drags(ID_Name) {
    $("body").append(function(){
    var $div = $("<div/>");
    $div.attr("id", ID_NAME);
    $div.addClass("ui-widget-content");
    $div.append("<p>Draggable</p>");

    $div.draggable();
    return $div;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will fix the problem and avoid using a selector on a just created element :

```
function create_drags(ID_Name) {
  $('<div id="'+ ID_Name +'" class="ui-widget-content"><p>Draggable</p></div>')
    .appendTo('body')
    .draggable();
}
```